# A dropdown menu something similar to the image posted

Tags: jquery, html, css, styling

Could someone provide me a menu like this one on the image below?

I would appreciate your help truly.

When clicking on top of email, the menu expands with the arrow upwards, but by default, arrow is pointing down if mouse is not clicked on top of the email.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVrBj.png)

Thanks and regards in advance.

here is the code almost there but need to make it on click and no disappear if one removes mouse over it after clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item-link {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(89,87,87,0.9);
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-item {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item-link:hover {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-item {
    display: table-row;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item.active {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item.active .menu-item-link:after {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);     
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
    <li class = "active menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">myname@gmail.com</a>
    </li>     
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 4</a>
    </li>           
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to fix this. Your code is running on CSS hover so I wrote a simple jQuery code and it changes your arrow direction on hover by applying different classes.

I've added two classes to your CSS one is arrow-up and the other, arrow-down.
I have not changed anything else but adding these two classes and changing your active menue item to :

```
<li class = "active menu-item">
    <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">myname@gmail.com <div class="arrow arrow-up"></div></a>
</li>
```

So, as you can see now you can toggle the class of your arrow div whenever you want.

What I would suggest is that; if you trying to do this on click, you have to rewrite your CSS and apply classes(or toggle them) when the dropdown-menu is clicked.

If you are using bootstrap; I, usually for this, use font awesome chevron up and down and just toggle the class of my `<i></i>` element.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click( function() {
    var arrow = $(this).find('i');
    // you can use .slideToggle() on your items to show them after click
    arrow .toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
});
```

anyways, here's your code. you can try it here.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').hover( function() {
var arrow = $(this).find('.arrow');
 arrow.toggleClass('arrow-up').toggleClass('arrow-down');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item-link {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(89,87,87,0.9);
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-item {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item-link:hover {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-item {
    display: table-row;
}
.dropdown-menu .menu-item.active {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);     
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;

}
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 8px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);     
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
    <li class = "active menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">myname@gmail.com <div class="arrow arrow-up"></div></a>
    </li>     
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a href = "#" class = "menu-item-link">Item 4</a>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

Comment: bro almost doing it but its working on hover i wanted it to be on click also i tried the down arrow would not work somehow on my localhost

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/en99dtn4/), this sample works with click however, it has lots of changes from your original question.